# How can I setstate before making function call in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick

```
<li
  key={suggestion.id}
  id={`suggestion-${index}`}
  className="suggestion-list-item"
  onClick={e => this.props.checkToShare(e, suggestion)}
>
```

How can I add `setState` and then call the `prop func` on my `onClick` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call setState and use its callback function:

```
 this.setState({...}, ()=>{ /* other function */})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) in setState that will be triggered once your state is updated:

```js
const handleClick = evt => {
  this.setState(..., () => {
    this.props.checkToShare(evt, suggestion)
  })
}
...

<li
  key={suggestion.id}
  id={`suggestion-${index}`}
  className="suggestion-list-item"
  onClick={handleClick}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just and {} for arrow function

```
   <li
      key={suggestion.id}
      id={`suggestion-${index}`}
      className="suggestion-list-item"
      onClick={e => {
        this.setState({ clicked: "yes" });
        this.props.checkToShare(e, suggestion);
      }}
    ></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better go for another async method for a cleaner code.

```
<li
  key={suggestion.id}
  id={`suggestion-${index}`}
  className="suggestion-list-item"
  onClick={e => this.cleanerWay(e,suggestion)}
>

cleanerWay=async(e,suggestion)=>{
/**setting state**/
await this.setState({suggestion});
/**calling the action**/
await this.props.checkToShare(e, suggestion);
}
```